# Interpolating code delimited with character that can appear in code

Tags: c#, python, parsing

I've got a string that consists of an arbitrary combination of text and `{}` delimited python code, for instance, `A plus b is {a + b}`.  However, braces are used for dictionary and set literals in python, so `You chose the {{1:"first", 2:"second"}[choice]} option` should also be interpretted correctly.  It's also valid to have more than one python expression in the input, so `You picked {choice1} and {choice2}` is valid.

Here's my current code:

```
protected String ParseStringForVariable([NotNull] String str)
{
    PythonEngine.PythonEngine pythonEngine = GetCurrentCore().PythonEngine;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != '{')
        {
            continue;
        }

        int opening = i;
        foreach (var expression in from closing in str.IndexesWhere('}'.Equals)
                                   where closing > opening
                                   select new
                                          {
                                              Template = str.Substring(opening, closing - opening + 1),
                                              Code = str.Substring(opening + 1, closing - opening - 1)
                                          })
        {
            PythonByteCode compiled;
            try
            {
                compiled = pythonEngine.Compile(expression.Code, PythonByteCode.SourceCodeType.Expression);
            }
            catch (PythonParseException)
            {
                // not valid python, try next expression
                continue;
            }
            String result = pythonEngine.Evaluate(compiled).ToString();
            str = str.Replace(expression.Template, result);
            break;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

It works by looking at progressively longer strings, attempting to parse them, and ignoring them if it's not valid python.  This is done with the `PythonEngine` class, which is a wrapper around the IronPython interpretter, and has an extensive test suite, so can assumed to be correct.

1. It appears to burp slightly if the value of the first of multiple python expression contains an opening brace: `{"{"} {"}"}`, what's the best way to prevent that?
2. Resharper is complaining about access to modified closures, can you provide a test case that exposes why that is an issue?
3. It works under all inputs I've tested it with, but what edge cases should be included in the test suite? (It's intended behaviour that invalid python code is left as-is).  Current thoughts include:

   - Empty string
   - without braces
   - empty braces
   - valid python in braces
   - invalid python
   - both valid and invalid
   - both valid and empty
   - both invalid and empty
   - valid, nested braces
   - invalid, nested braces
   - valid, evaluated to contain open brace
   - valid, evaluated to contain close brace - irrelevant, as parsing is LTR?
   - valid, evaluated to contain open brace followed by further invalid
   - valid, evaluated to contain open brace followed by further empty
   - unmatched open brace
   - unmatched close brace
4. Are there any improvements that jump out?  Clarity, performance, style?

Comment: What are you using to execute the Python code? I can't seem to find types like `PythonByteCode` anywhere.

Comment: @svick Post edited to clarify.

Comment: reg 3.) Could you please add your test cases.

Comment: @mnhg clarified slightly, but added.

Comment: Regarding #2: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8898925/298754

Comment: @Bobson perhaps I'm just being dense, but I still don't get how that applies in this case. Hence asking for a test case: it works as expected in every situation I've tried.  Or is it just Resharper being over-cautious?

Comment: Where is it complaining?

Comment: `str.Substring()` in the anonymous object constructor.

Comment: This bit is troubling to me: `str = str.Replace(expression.Template, result);` You may want to push the result of the replacement on a stack instead of overwriting the `str`. What does the `i` mean in the outer loop after you replace an expression with its value, which usually is of a different length? I will have to come up with some test cases on weekend to definitely say that this is a bug, but I can at least say it is definitely confusing to read.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca That's the reason I'm using `i` rather than a foreach: After the replacement, `i` is the index of the first character of the result.  I was tempted to add a line like `i += result.Length`... I can't remember the reasoning on why I didn't.

Comment: Also, I'm replacing in place so that open braces in the code don't get parsed again: `this is a set: {{1,2}}` `{1,2}` is a valid set literal, `1,2` is a valid tuple literal.

Answer (score 2):

I see an extra unnecessary variable that you can get rid of, or change another variable so that it makes more sense.

```
int opening = i;
```

you use this inside of a for loop.  You can do 2 things with this.

1. Just use the variable `i` where ever you had the variable `opening`
2. change the `i` variable to `opening` in the for loop like

   ```
   for (int opening = 0; opening < str.Length; opening++)
   ```

hopefully this shows you how unnecessary that extra variable is, it isn't used anywhere else for anything other than the loops.

---

Other than that I would need to play with it and spend some time with it to see if it plays well with others.